# converting the column of a dataframe into a timestamp

Tags: python-datetime

I am reading a dataframe into pandas.  It is time series data from an ECG.  I have two columns: the first column is the time the reading is taken, the second column is the value from the ECG.  I am trying to convert the first column into the timestamp and use it as an index.  My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path='/home/user_1/Documents/heart_data.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(path)
df.columns=['Elapsed Time','i']
df['Elapsed Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Elapsed Time'], format="'%H:%M.%S%f'") 
df.set_index('Elapsed Time', inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

My problem is that this gives me the output of the column in the form '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', but I do not want the '1900-01-01' just the time.
How can I get rid of the date appearing in my column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Let's create a dataframe.
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['1920-01-01 00:00:00.000','1900-01-01 22:00:00.000']},index=[1,2])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df
                 date
1 1920-01-01 00:00:00
2 1900-01-01 22:00:00

df=df['date'].dt.time #This will only give you Time part

df
1    00:00:00
2    22:00:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```